Creating folders in OneDrive via PowerShell
I am unable to create files/folders in my OneDrive, I got this message:
Resolve-PnPFolder : The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden
Microsoft changed how to connect via PnP and now no one can connect with a user.
I do have an application and I am trying to connect with ClientID and Secret when connecting I am getting this warning:
WARNING: Connecting with Client Secret uses legacy authentication and provides limited functionality. We can for instance not execute requests towards the Microsoft Graph, which limits cmdlets related to Microsoft Teams, Microsoft Planner, Microsoft Flow and Microsoft 365 Groups. You can hide this warning by using Connect-PnPOnline [your parameters] -WarningAction Ignore
I added almost everything in App permissions and still got this message, what could be the reason?
$OneDriveSiteURL = "https://XXXXtest104-my.sharepoint.com/personal/agileqa_XXXXXtest104_onmicrosoft_com"

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $OneDriveSiteURL -ClientId "3ed262a0-f02e-48f4-9ede-ef90c76aXXXX" -ClientSecret "dAs8Q~XXXXkdmF4bF3UI1Hke2yxtTgXXXX"

I can tell that we used a Nuget that someone prepared and it worked as expected with the same App registration, we must use PowerShell instead of this Nuget (there is a reason for that...)
I used this and it's working but it creates a folder in SPO and not in OD why?

OneDrive FB create Folder with Microsoft Graph API Powershell
$clientId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
$tenantId = "XXXXXX.onmicrosoft.com"
$clientSecret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'


$uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"


$body = @{
    client_id     = $clientId
    scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
    client_secret = $clientSecret
    grant_type    = "client_credentials"
}

$tokenRequest = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri $uri -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -Body $body -UseBasicParsing
$token = ($tokenRequest.Content | ConvertFrom-Json).access_token
Write-Host $token


$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/<ID XXXXXXX>/drive/root/children"
$method = 'POST'
$head= @{Authorization = "Bearer $token"} 
$postPara= @{
name= "NewFolder"
folder= {}
} | ConvertTo-Json


$antwort = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $head -Uri $uri -Method $method -Body $postPara -ContentType "application/json"
Write-Host $antwort


First of all, please clarify which version of the PnP Module you are using.
Is it SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline, or is it PnP.PowerShell?
Also, please clarify what you need an answer on: How to use PnP to create a Folder in a OneDrive SiteCollection, or use the Graph API to create a Folder in a OneDrive SiteCollection

PnP.PowerShell version 1.12 needs to create a folder in OD in any way using client ID and secret. when I am using -UseWebLogin it worked but this should work automatically without any popup

If you need to use PnP.PowerShell, you should use a Certificate instead of an App Secret. The decprecation of using AppSecrets for the SharePoint Online CSOM is a given by Microsoft, and the PnP.PowerShell module makers have no influence on that (https://github.com/pnp/powershell/issues/1558).
Changing to a certificate instead of an AppSecret should resolve your issue:
Reference on how to do that here:
https://pnp.github.io/powershell/articles/authentication.html#non-interactive-authentication
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread
